# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x\cdot\ln x)^n$ for $x\in(0,1]$

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

How can I prove or disprove uniform convergence $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x\cdot\ln x)^n$$ for $x\in(0,1]$?

Comment: Trying to use the Weierstrass test. But do not understand how I can?

Comment: Hint: can you find an upper bound for $|x\ln x|$ on these values of $x$? This will help you construct the upper bound $M_n$ for your sequence

Comment: Yes, but I have power of n. How do I get rid of n?

Comment: You don't have to: if $|x\ln x| \leq a,$ then for any positive integer $n, |(x \ln x)^n| \leq a^n.$ So let $M_n = a^n.$

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, have a good one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $x \in (0,1]$ you have that $|x\ln(x)|\leq e^{-1}$, thus $$
\left| {\left( {x\ln x} \right)^n } \right| = \left| {\left( {x\ln x} \right)} \right|^n  \le e^{ - n} 
$$ for every integer  $n\geq 1$. Since the numerical series
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {e^{ - n} } 
$$
by Weierstrass M-Test you get the uniform convergence of your series.

Comment: That's exactly what I did

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$\lvert x\ln x\rvert \leq x^2,$$

and so $x\ln x\to 0$ as $x\to0^+$ This means that $x\ln x$ is bounded for $x\in(0,1]$ (this is easy to see as we could extend it to a continuous function on $[0,1]$ as the limit as $x\to0^+$ exists, and all continuous functions on compact intervals are bounded), and so there is some $\alpha>0$ such that

$$\lvert x\ln x\rvert\leq \alpha.$$

Using some basic calculus is it also easy to see that $\alpha<1$. Thus, setting $M_n=\alpha^n$, we have that

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+ :\forall x\in(0,1] : \lvert x\ln x\rvert^n\leq M_n, \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{j=1}^\infty M_j<\infty,$$

where the series converges as it is a convergent geometric series (as $\alpha\in(0,1)$). It follows by the Weierstrass M-test that the series

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty (x\ln x)^j$$

converges absolutely and uniformly on $(0,1]$.